# Header height and positioning header from top of page in wkhtmltopdf

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

In my application, the user is allowed to define his own headers and margins for printing.
For the header, the user can provide the following two fields:

- (a) Page Top Margin in mm (from top of the page)
- (b) Header Margin in mm (from top of the page)

The fields (a) and (b) are as shown in the figure below:
[image: Margins depiction]

For example, if the user provides (a) as 10mm and (b) as 100mm, then the height of the 'Header Region' would be 90mm.

Now the content within the header needs to be aligned at the top of the Header Region.

Is there a way to set the Header Region Height and to top-align the content within this header region.

At present, i am doing the following for the **header-html** option:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <style type="text/css">
        body 
        {
            border:0; 
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 90mm;  //in actual program, this is set dynamically in PHP
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function subst() 
    {
        //process the GET parameters and accordingly set the Header Region text info
    }  
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="subst()">
    <div>
        //text
    </div>
</body>  
</html>
```

The **margin-top** option is being set as 100mm.

I have tried setting *vertical-align: top* for the *body* CSS, But that too did not work.

The final output that I achieve does not seem to have the Header Region content vertical aligned in either top or middle. It is somewhere a little above the middle of the Header Region.

Comment: try using the wkhtmltopdf flag for `spacing` in addition to `margin-top`

Comment: @Unixmonkey: the header region content does not have a fixed size. The user is free to provide any no. of lines for the header content. So the spacing cannot be pre-fixed. Also, i did not mention earlier, even the paper-size is user-defined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit**: This fix seems to be required only when *wkhtmltopdf* is installed in a Windows based system.

After lot of trial and error, I observed that the following logic seems to be work:

- The *body* element of **html-head** needs to be set to an height 1.33 times the actual height of the Header Region. (Why? I do not know. This could be due to some QT or wkhtmltopdf way of rendering, but it actually works for all cases, irrespective of the lines in the Header Region content).
- The immediate (and the only) child element of the body is set to 100% height and to hide the overflowing content

So, the changed code (for the above example) for *html-head* looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <style type="text/css">
        body 
        {
            border:0; 
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 120mm;
            /*
            In the actual program this height is calculated dynamically in PHP as
            ($headerMargin - $topMargin) * 1.33
            */
        }

        #master-div
        {
            overflow: hidden;
            height: 100%;
        }

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function subst() 
    {
        //process the GET parameters and accordingly set the Header Region text info
    }  
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="subst()">
    <div id="master-div">
        //The actual content goes here
    </div>
</body>  
</html>
```

I have checked this for atleast 7 to 8 different paper sizes (including setting custom *page-width* and *page-height*. Also checked with different Header Region content size (ranging from 1 line to 20 lines).

The only catch is that this logic of 1.33 times the header region height seems to work only if the Header Margin(b)/Footer Margin is less than or equal to one-third the paper-height. If the margin height goes beyond that the content gets clipped as the margin-height increases. But having such large header-heights would generally not be required, i guess.

Comment: I was able to deal with the PDF using the knowledge you provided, but I'm still a bit confused about the margins and positioning. Also, my PDF has been generating blank pages (only with headers), which is leading me to believe content is pushing something to the next page.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your problem(s)? Also note that the problem and solution is only when you are running wkhtmltopdf in a Windows machine. If the final hosting is going to be done on a Linux machine, the above problem does not occur. In such case (where developing on Windows and hosting on Linux), you have to deal with both the situations individually, i.e., have different PHP/CSS for each case. Atleast that is what i have done.

Comment: I'm working on Windows, as our solution is ASP.NET-based. Still, I was able to manage a correct header, even though I'm not yet able to figure out the numbers (I could do it after some trial and error). You can see a PDF example here: http://bit.ly/1acl3DW which was generated from ASP.NET using the following command: http://pastebin.com/KdMCv8VB

Comment: As an example, if you require Header Height (b) of 20mm and your Top Margin (a) is 4mm, then the 'height' for your "html-head" CSS should be (20-4)*1.33mm = 21.28mm. And in wkhtmltopdf options, set the 'margin-top' parameter to 20mm. Note that the CSS mentioned in this comment would go into the 'body' tag of the CSS, as shown in the solution.

Comment: Ok, thanks! What if I require no margins on the first page (cover) and regular header margins on the following pages? Would I have to treat each page separately in javascript?

Comment: This should be achievable through Javascript in the header-html file. You will need to refer to the wkhtmltopdf Manual http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf_0.10.0_rc2-doc.html. Basically, you can pass your own parameters in the header-html url, ex: --header-html headerFile.html?parameters. The parameters are of key-value type and seperated by '&' as done in standard URL GET format. Wkhtmltopdf itself passes some parameters such as frompage, topage etc. These are passed after your custom parameters. The manual shows an example of how to play with these parameters in js.

Comment: Sorry, i got confused with custom parameters. I guess for your use-case, your own solution is more appropriate. You will have to treat them as separate pages and join them through wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: Thanks, @mohitp. That's what I thought I'd have to do. :) I gave up the cover page due to time restrictions, but I'll sure get back to it later.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are doing here. You are setting the margin-top of the document itself to 20mm. But you only want a 4mm top margin, and a 20mm header height. You then set the height rule of the HTML element of the header to 20-4 * 1.33? This is wild. Does anyone understand this relationship? Is this still the rule in the current build?

Let's say I have a header that I want to occupy the entire top margin of 4mm. What would I set the html element height too? 4mm doesn't seem to be right. and 4mm * 1.33mm isn't right either. (4-4) * 1.33 is obviously 0.